# Diagonals of $2n$-gon bisecting area implies?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

For a convex (or no diagonals connecting opposite vertices leaving the hexagon) hexagon $ABCDEF,$ if $AD, BE,$ and $CF$ all bisect the area, then they are concurrent. This can be proven in multiple ways, one of which uses the fact that the condition implies $AC$ is parallel to $DF,$ and similarly for the other two pairs, and then there's a homothety taking $ACE$ to $BDF$ (something like that), so the center of homothety is the intersection point. Alternatively, you can intersect $AD$ and $BE,$ say at $X,$ and note that $AX\cdot XB = DX\cdot EX$ by the condition, and if the last diagonal doesn't concur at $X,$ you can do a sort of cyclic product where one side ends up being bigger than the other.

Anyway, I'm interested in knowing whether or not this can be generalized to $2n$-gons for $n > 3.$ What is true is that if you have this pairwise homothety as in the $n=3$ case, then the claim follows, but I'm not sure if just having area bisectors is enough, since it seems to rely on the fact that upon intersecting any two diagonals in the hexagon you get triangles.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be true, if you consider that figure to have an uniform weight distribution, then each of bisecting diagonals will go through the center of mass because they will be plumb lines (the areas next to the diagonals exert the same pressure on the diagonals) and each plumb line goes through the center of mass.
This is a proof using physics though, not math.
source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locating_the_center_of_mass

Comment: Bisecting diagonals don't really need to go through the center of mass on a generic shape