# Diagonals dividing an hexagon into regions of the same area.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, area

Say a **diagonal** of a convex polygon with an even number of vertices is a line segment connecting opposite vertices.

I've found the following problem in an old exercise list a teacher gave me:

> If each of the three diagonals of a convex hexagon divides it into regions of the same area, show that the three diagonals meet at the same point.

In the image below I marked the areas determined by the diagonals.

[image: hexagon]

My first impulse was to try to show that $P = 0$. For this I set up the following system:

$$\begin{cases}
T/2 &= A+B+Y\\
T/2 &= B+C+Z\\
T/2 &= C+A+X\\
T/2 &= X+Y+A+P\\
T/2 &= Y+Z+B+P\\
T/2 &= Z+X+C+P\\
\end{cases}$$

Where $T = A+B+C+X+Y+Z+P$ is the hexagon's total area. The system may be simplified to

$$\begin{cases}
A &= Z+P\\
B &= X+P\\
C &= Y+P
\end{cases}$$

but I don't see how to proceed from that point. Also, I wonder if the same statement is true by replacing the hexagon with a $2n-$agon. Of course, in this case, writing a system with the areas would become unfeasible, so a smarter approach would be needed.

---

**Update:** My approach was deemed to failure, as pointed out by a comment, since three segments dividing a polygon into regions of the same area are not required to concur.

[image]

The fact that some of the regions are triangles seems to be important. This is a negative indicative for the more general question. Moreover, I've just now found out the general problem had already been posted in the Math Stack Exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1333466/754030), though it have not been properly answered. It does provide, however, a much pretty proof for the hexagonal case.

Comment: On your drawing I see a general figure and three lines, each cutting it in halves. You never make use of the fact that it is a hexagon. It could have been anything. It could have been an _amoeba_, and the equations would still look the same. But guess what? For a general figure, $P=0$ is **not necessarily true**.

Comment: @IvanNeretin what kind of figure could have $P\neq 0$, then?

Comment: An equilateral triangle would do, if the three lines are parallel to its sides.

Comment: @Arjuna196, In your last system of equations if p=0 that would mean the areas (A and z), (B and X) and (C and Y) are all symmetric about a single point which is the intersection of Diagonals. I think this can be sufficient if the sides of poly gone are equal. This is because of common side created triangles have.

Answer (score 5):

The area of a triangle $\triangle ABC$ is $\frac12 ab\sin \widehat{C}$.

In your figure, triangles $Z+P$ and $A$ share an angle, so the product of corresponding sides are equal. The same with $Y+P$ and $C$, and with $X+P$ and $B$. So the product of six sides of $X+P$, $Y+P$ and $Z+P$ equal six sides of $A$, $B$ and $C$.  But the sides of the former are longer than the latter, unless $P$ is a point.

Comment: This is a very satisfying demonstration! Do you think it would be possible to adapt it to the case of a polygon with $2n$ sides?

Comment: That takes a little thought.

Answer (score 1):

This is only true for hexagons. There's a way to make counter examples for $n \geq 4$ and here's a [geogebra applet](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/qf5ttck8) showing a counterexample for the case $n=4$. Now, I present how to make such counterexamples.

Let $n \geq 4$ and $P = A_1 \dots A_{2n}$ be our polygon. Also, to simplify notation, think of $P$ as a sequence of points mod $2n$ so that by $A_{2n+1}$ I mean $A_1$.

**Definition 1:** We say $P$ is bissective if every segment $A_iA_{i+n}$ splits it into two polygons of equal area.

**Lemma 2:** If $P$ is bissective, then the segments $A_i A_{n+i+1}$ and $A_{i+1} A_{n+i}$ are parallel for all $i$.

**Proof:** It suffices to prove for $i=1$. Let $H$ be the intersection between these two segments. Notice that when we draw them, $P$ gets divided into four polygons. Let $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$ and $S_4$ be the areas of $A_1 A_2 H$, $A_{n+1} A_{n+2} H$, $A_2 A_3 \dots A_{n+1} H$ and $A_{n+2} A_{n+3} \dots A_{2n} A_1 H$ respectively. Since $P$ is bissective, $S_1+S_3 = S_2 + S_4$ and $S_1 + S_4 = S_2 + S_3$ (segments $A_1 A_{n+1}$ and $A_2 A_{n+2}$ split $P$ into polygons of same area). Thus, $S_1 = S_2$. Let $\alpha = \angle A_{n+2} H A_{n+1} = \angle A_2 H A_1$. It's known that

$$S_1 = [A_2 H A_1] = \dfrac{1}{2} A_2 H \cdot A_1 H \sin \alpha$$
$$S_2 = [A_{n+2} H A_{n+1}] = \dfrac{1}{2} A_{n+2} H \cdot A_{n+1} H \sin \alpha$$

Since $S_1 = S_2$, $\dfrac{A_2 H}{A_{n+2} H} = \dfrac{A_{n+1} H}{A_1 H}$. Now, notice that since we also have $\angle A_{n+1} H A_2 = \angle A_1 H A_{n+2}$, then $\Delta A_{n+1} H A_2 \sim \Delta A_1 H A_{n+2}$. In particular, $A_1 A_{n+2}$ is parallel to $A_2 A_{n+1}$. $\blacksquare$

**Remark:** Lemma 2 gives enough intuition for understanding the geometric construction done in the geogebra applet. The following theorem is just to wrap things up.

**Theorem 3:** $P$ is bissective if, and only if, the segments $A_i A_{n+i+1}$ and $A_{i+1} A_{n+i}$ are parallel for all $i$.

**Proof:** Lemma 2 proves one implication. It remains to prove the other one.

Suppose that the segments $A_i A_{n+i+1}$ and $A_{i+1} A_{n+i}$ are parallel for all $i$. Let $H_i$ be the intersection of $A_i A_{n+i}$ and $A_{i+1} A_{n+i+1}$. Trivial angle chasing gives us $\Delta A_{n+i} H_i A_{i+1} \sim \Delta A_{n+i+1} A_i H_i$, which means $A_{i+1} H_i \cdot A_i H_i = A_{n+i+1} H_i \cdot A_{n+i} H$ so that $[A_{i+1} H_i A_i] = [A_{n+i} A_{n+i+1} H_i]$ (this means that the last part of the previous lemma can be reversed).

Now we just need to prove that $A_1 A_{n+1}$ splits $P$ into two polygons with equal areas. Suppose it splits $P$ into two polygons with areas $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Also, suppose $A_2 A_{n+2}$ splits $P$ into two polygons with areas $S_3$ and $S_4$. Notice that if $S = [A_1 A_2 H_1] = [A_{n+1} A_{n+2} H_1]$, then $S_3 = S_1 - [A_1 A_2 H_1] + [A_{n+1} A_{n+2} H_1] = S_1$. Similarly, $S_4 = S_2$. It's like we "moved the areas clockwise".

Now, keep doing this on clockwise order until $A_{n+1} A_{2n+1}$. We then have "moved" $S_1$ and $S_2$ to each others original places, meaning $S_1 = S_2$. $\blacksquare$